# Request for two unpublished articles of Detlef Gromoll

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for two articles for my research purpose, which are entitled with "Convex riemannian manifolds" and "Convex sets in riemannian manifolds" by Detlef Gromoll.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me to have these papers. Thank you!